# How to change the tui-color-picker default color using @toast-ui/react-image-editor?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, toast-ui-image-editor

I'm using the https://ui.toast.com/tui-image-editor library for a image edition functionality, there's a color picker component that comes by default there, I'm trying to change the default color of this color-picker but I can't find a way to do that, I've done some research and looks like this image-editor is using https://github.com/nhn/tui.color-picker as a dependency, so that may be way it's so hard to change the color.

Here's my code:

```
 <ImageEditor ref={this.editorRef} {...imageEditorOptions} 
            includeUI={{
              loadImage: {'image-path'},
              theme: myTheme,
              menu: ['text'],
              initMenu: 'text',
              menuBarPosition: 'bottom',
            }}
            selectionStyle={{
              cornerSize: 20,
              rotatingPointOffset: 70,
            }}
        />
```

On the "myTheme" variable I've setup some configurations for the color-pick style, but they haven't been working for setting its default color, probably because it's setup dynamically.

```
'colorpicker.button.border': '1px solid #1e1e1e',
'colorpicker.title.color': '#fff'
```

I've also tried setting up the color directly on my page CSS

```
.tui-image-editor-container .tui-image-editor-main-container {
    bottom: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    max-height: 450px;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is currently no option to change the default colors of the color picker,
refer here: https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor/issues/258

a workaround this, is to make use of the [startDrawingMode](https://nhn.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/ImageEditor#startDrawingMode) method

so you can create your own color picker or use the tui color picker and then invoke the StartDrawingMode method using your own function, here is how I do it in Vue (Nuxt.js)

```
<MyColorPicker @colorPicked="startDrawing" />

<tui-image-editor ref="imageEditor">
</tui-image-editor>

startDrawing({ color, drawStyle, size }) {
      this.$refs.imageEditor.invoke('stopDrawingMode')
      this.$refs.imageEditor.invoke('startDrawingMode', drawStyle, {
        width: size,
        color,
      })
    }
```

drawStyle can be 'FREE_DRAWING' or 'LINE_DRAWING'

this code is in Vue (Nuxt.js) but I believe it is fairly similar it React